# Show that the function $f(x)$ given $f'(x) = \frac{e^{3x} g(x)}{x}$ where $g(x) = 1 + 3x\ln(x)$ has exactly two local extrema.

Tags: real-analysis

I am given $f'(x) = \frac{e^{3x} g(x)}{x}$ where $g(x) = 1 + 3x\ln(x)$ and am asked to 
a) Find the monotonicity of $g(x)$ and show it has exactly two roots. 
b) Show that f has exactly two local extrema.

For a) I was able to find that $g(x)$ is monotonically decreasing on $(0, e^{-1}]$ and monotonically increasing on $[e^{-1}, +\infty)$. 
Using the IVT on the intervals $[\frac{1}{5}, e^{-1}]$ and $[e^{-1}, 1]$ as well as the monotonicity on each interval I was able to prove that $g(x)$ has exactly two roots.

I am a bit confused on how to show that $f(x)$ has exactly two local extrema given that I don't know the exact value of the roots.

Comment: What do you mean by "the exact value of the roots"? Haven't you already solved the problem?

Comment: The statement *show it has exactly two roots*, does not mean to find the positions of the roots *exactly*, but rather to find the *exact number* of the roots.